# Bundle libgfortran with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

The manylinux-Wheels on PyPI all ship with their own copies of libgfortran (and blas).

How can I include them in my own builds?  I’ve looked through the docs and even read the travis scripts in the repo but couldn’t find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manylinux wheels are described in [PEP 513 -- A Platform Tag for Portable Linux Built Distributions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/).

The critical steps include:

1. Build the wheel on a platform where the libraries (most importantly the C library) is compatible with more recent platforms. This is achieved by building on the Docker image of CentOS 5.11
2. Bundle the required libraries in the wheel (while still being in the CentOS Docker image). There is a tool, [auditwheel](https://github.com/pypa/python-manylinux-demo) that has been developed for this specific purpose.

The current process has been achieved with a lot of trial and error and testing. If you wish to build a manylinux wheel yourself, you can use the same tools as "official" packages such as NumPy, they are provided on the GitHub repo: [pypa/python-manylinux-demo](https://github.com/pypa/python-manylinux-demo) is a demo project that uses the build process for manylinux wheels.

EDIT: For SciPy, the actual project wheels building is based on https://github.com/MacPython/scipy-wheels/